# How to update a specific subdocument with mongoose. (3 levels deep)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document scheme

```
var restsSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    menu: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

and an actual simplified document looks like:

```
{
    name: "Dominos Pizza"
    phoneNumber: "1800800800"
    menu:{
             "1":{
                  name: "Plain Pizza",
                  soldCounter: 0
               },
             "2":{
                  name: "Pizza with vegetables",
                  soldCounter: 0
                }
         }
}
```

my question is how can i update a specific `soldCounter` without saving the entire document.

I guess i will need to change the Scheme definition.
* I'm really new to mongoose and mongoDB. so be gentle ;)

Comment: The answer should be in mongoose code.

Answer (score 2):

With dot notation.

```
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("...")}, {$set: {"menu.1.soldCounter": 1}});
```

or

```
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("...")}, {$inc: {"menu.1.soldCounter": 1}})
```

Comment: what if i want to increment the counter in both `menu.1` and `menu.2`?
lets say i have an array of these elements.

Comment: how can i achieve that using mongoose?

Comment: [mongoose update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)

if I get you right:
`Model.update({_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId('...)}, {$inc: {"menu.1.soldCounter": 1, "menu.2.soldCounter": 1, ...}})`